# Collection - Model usage for JSON response?

Tags: json, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Regarding the pattern Backbone uses for Collections and Models , I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve is possible.

I am wanting the Collection to act as a constructor by making a AJAX POST request to fetch JSON. Using that JSON response it will instantiate multiple models and add them to an array.

Each object has the attributes which will be stored in my model e.g.

```
    define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function (_, Backbone)
{
    'use strict';

    var Employee= Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            name: '',
            skill: '',
            latitude : 0,
            longitude : 0
        },

    });

    return Employee;
});
```

**JSON Response**

```
[
{
    "name" : "bob",
    "skill" : "project manager",
    "latitude" : 12512.25,
    "longitude" : 95952.26
},


{
    "name" : "sarah",
    "skill" : "software dev",
    "latitude" : 89432.25,
    "longitude" : 1205.26
},


{
    "name" : "tom",
    "skill" : "evil sys admin",
    "latitude" : 1215,
    "longitude" : 92325
}
```

]

**Collection**

```
    define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/employee'
], function (_, Backbone, Store, Employee) {
    'use strict';

    var Employees = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        // Reference to this collection's model.
        model: Employee,

    });

    return new Employees();
});
```

**Code**

```
emps = new Employees();
emps.url("/testURL"); //
emps.sync();

emps.model[0]; //undefined !!!
```

So from that I can conclude that the Collection is not smart enough to instantiate an array of Employee models from the JSON response.
How can I do this?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to use `emps.fetch()`?

Comment: No, because I am not using REST style, I am using Sync to make a POST request and want to consume its response

Comment: I believe that sync also creates a [REST](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) style request (in fact [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) proxies to `sync`). You are able to override both your collections' `sync` method and it's parse methods to match your server's web service.

Comment: Another thing, being that `sync` is asynchronous you aren't properly testing to see if your collection is getting back any data, you need to do that in the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch). Fetch uses `sync` to fetch data, and then instantiates models accordingly.

If your API doesn't respond to a `GET /someurl` then what you need to override is the [sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sync) method. Read the source to see how it works.

Also, you're not using url properly. It should be a string, or a function that returns a string.

```
var employees = new Employees();
employees.url = '/my/testurl';
// note that fetch is async
employees.fetch().done(function () {
  console.log(employees.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your collection constructor code is getting `undefined` as its input array, and thus remains empty.

You want to pass your collection into your Employees constructor, like

`var emps = new Employees(arrayOfEmployees, {model: Employee});`

Also, that last part (re-specifying the model) is likely not necessary.

Comment: @loosebruce nothing is making a request here, this is how you can pass in array of models to *bootstrap* data initially or if you were making the request yourself manually.

Comment: @loosebruce It can, that's what `fetch` is for. I'm just pointing out that as far as I can see this answer doesn't really address your question.